# How to return JSON response in Django's HttpResponseServerError?

Tags: json, ajax, django

I am writing a python Django application where I am returning error HttpResponseServerError. I also need to return some json data that i can get a message from and show to the user in my front end. So I am doing like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseServerError
def my_test_500_view(request):
        return HttpResponseServerError(json.dumps({'error': 'An error occured'}, content_type="application/json")
```

But in my front end, I can't seem to get the value for `'error'`.

In my front end Ajax, I am doing like this:

```
$("#input_submit").click(function () {
              var input = $("#input").val();

              $.ajax({
                url: 'my_url',
                data: {
                  'input': input,
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.error);
                }
              });

            });
```

Where `console.log(data.error);` returns `undefined`. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py try returning:

```
 return HttpResponseServerError(json.dumps({'error': 'An error occured'}))
```

In your template instead of `data.error`, try:

```
data.responseText
```